# Need help in understanding NAGIOS NRPE commands

Tags: ubuntu, centos, nagios

I have centOS5 where i have installed the Nagios Monitoring system
Ubuntu - is the remote host where i have insalled the NRPE plugin and addon

Now on REMOTE HOST UBUNUT --MY NRPE.CFG SAYS

```
command[check_total_procs]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_procs -w 350 -c 500

command[check_http]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_http -I 127.0.0.1 -w 150 -c 200
command[check_ssh]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_ssh 127.0.0.1
```

CENTOS -- HOST  has two file 
localhost.cfg

```
define service{
                use                     generic-service
                host_name               remotehost
                service_description     Total Processes
                check_command           check_nrpe!check_total_procs
}



define service{
                use                     generic-service
                host_name               remotehost
                service_description     APACHE Processes
                check_command           check_nrpe!check_http 192.168.1.95
}

define service{
                use                     generic-service
                host_name               remotehost
                service_description     SSH
                check_command           check_nrpe!check_ssh 127.0.0.1
}
```

and commands.cfg

```
# 'check_http' command definition
define command{
        command_name    check_http
        command_line    $USER1$/check_http -I $HOSTADDRESS$ $ARG1$
        }


# 'check_ssh' command definition
define command{
        command_name    check_ssh
        command_line    $USER1$/check_ssh $ARG1$ $HOSTADDRESS$
        }
```

---

THe process command was already in so that is working fine for remote host.

I have myself added the command for http and ssh but i don't know how to use it because

for process , i can understand that  w 20 means warning for process more than 20 but how can i use w,c for http and ssh. i am confused as there is no number associated with it.

also where can i enter the IP address while using http and ssh because with above data my http works by hit and trail but shh is not working. it says use properly

Answer (score 2):

Look at the man pages for check_http and check_ssh. Those two checks are usually ran directly from the nagios server and NOT used in conjunction with NRPE (exceptions exist).

The warning and critical thresholds are related to response time. You can also modify what http response codes are acceptable.

http://nagiosplugins.org/man/check_http
http://nagiosplugins.org/man/check_ssh

Please rephrase your second question as it does not currently make sense. Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for that , i didn't knew there are help pages for command. Also how can i run those commands directly. because if i use nrpe then those will be executed from localhost and they will always be ok , i want to check whether those services are ok to outside world or not

Answer (score 0):

It would be advisable to perform your monitoring from another machine.  If networking is lost on your one machine, not only does your main site go down but so does your warning system and you won't know it.